# ImageField not showing up on Orchard 1.8 site Admin Modules panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Installed a Clean Orchard Site via WebMatrix and upon installing an ImageField, either via command line or via the Admin Panel, i get this error:

> The assembly reference 'Orchard.Media' could not be loaded for module 'Contrib.ImageField'.

I can't seem to get the module to work as a content field.

i see the module created in the project modules but i cant seem to have an option to enable it.
tried the command line:

> feature enable Contrib.ImageField

But i keep getting:

> Error executing command "feature enable Contrib.ImageField"
>
> Failed to get state for feature Orchard.Media

I see Orchard.Media in the project root and the installed module Contrib.ImageField.

any thoughts?

Thanks,
Idan

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Contrib.ImageField: it was for very old versions of Orchard, and is now completely obsolete. Use the built-in Media Library Picker Field instead. No need to install anything, it comes with Orchard 1.8.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I was looking for a file select module for image upload, and the ImageField was supposed to work on latest orchard version.

Comment: Using the Media Library picker wont allow me to just upload an image from local computer into a content item...

Comment: Who said it was supposed to work on the latest Orchard? Why wouldn't the media library picker allow you to upload images?? Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I figured out using the latest version of Contrib.imagefield isn't a solution, so thanks. I guess you didn't really understand my reply though. Using the media picker gives a different behaviour than desired. i wanted a simple upload image to the Content item. not a folder creation and media management section. just wanted to know if there's any input before i need to build my own module, which i wanted to avoid. Thanks again

Comment: `MediaLibraryPicker` is not an option in case you want to attach `logo` to `CompanyItem` for example. it is really unusable to view hundreeds of logos every time you need to upload new one. So in this case you need just field with will upload image, rename it to `YourCustomFolder\field_name-id.*` and resize as you need. thats all, no MediaLibrary required.